# In single player in Mario Kart 64, who wins in a tie in points?

Tags: mario-kart-64

My friend and I are trying to get all the 150cc Gold Cups in Mario Kart 64. However, we got in a points situation in the last race of the cup where the only way we could get first in points was by getting in first place, Wario placing 2nd or worse, and DK placing 3rd or worse. Even in that situation, it would be a three-way tie for first place. How would the cup be awarded?

Comment: Going based on the GC version I'd say total time, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is a tie in the end of a GP, the human player will beat the CPUs. In 2-player GPs, player 1 will beat player 2 if they are tied.

Comment: That's why you always make your friends be second player!

Comment: @ponsfonze AND give them the crappy controller!

Answer (score 1):

If you play alone against a CPU in Mario Kart 64 and tie for time against the CPU, you will be ranked base on if you beat that CPU in the previous race. If you won the previous race you will be ranked above. If you tie for time during the first race you will be rank below the CPU, same goes for two CPU players. If you tie for time in 2 player Grand Prix in Mario Kart 64 Player 1 and player 2 will always be ranked above CPU, and if player 1 and player 2  tie, player 1 is rank above player 2, and if CPU tie against other CPU, they will be in order by CPU number. In 2 player Grand Prix CPU 1 is at the 6th place position before the  start of the race.

Comment: Do you have any source for this? It seems to contradict my past experiences.